# Cross-Compiling C++/QT from a Mac for WIndows, Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cross-compiling

I developed a C++/QT application and I am trying to compile it for Mac, Windows and Linux. I chose C++ just so I can make it compatible with these major operating systems. I can compile it for mac just fine.

I found out about Cross Compiling but some are outdated or not well documented... or does not guarantee they will work on the latest version of Windows or a Mac.

I do have Virtual Windows and Cent OS installed on my machine but I feel that compiling the application manually would be over kill.

So, do you recommend any reliable cross-compiler? Or is there any way to automate the compilation so if I have to, it can compile by logging on to my Virtual Windows or Cent OS installations?

FYI... not only cross compile but also generate 32 bit and 64 bit versions!

Answer (score 1):

For Mac and linux you don't have a big issue here if you got the g++ compiler installed in your OS. But you will need to install [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in the Windows installation to provide the gcc and the g++ compilers for your programs and if you want to automate your compilation process you can use a Makefile or try to see the [autotools](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotools).

Answer (score 1):

The only cross compiler that I know of is GCC. I have actually used it on Linux to cross-compile for S/390 a while back, and also to cross-compile ARM code on a Power Mac (I used [the instructions here](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/cross-toolchain-osx.html) to set it up).

That said, I think that what you want is to cross-compile Windows x64 on a 32 bit virtual machine running Windows. If that is the case you are lucky, because Microsoft actually gives away the cross compilers for free with the Windows SDK since Windows 2000 SDK. I actually use the Windows Vista SDK (ver 6.1) on Virtual PC running XP to compile for Windows x64. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24826) you can download the latest version of the SDK, which comes with the compilers. I looked on the system requirements and it still supports XP, so this should be good for you.

Please note that the compilers are the same that come with Visual Studio, but you will have to invoke them from the command line environment installed by the SDK by either using **'cl'** or **'nmake'**.

You can chose the compilation mode by issuing **SETENV /x86** for 32 bit or **SETENV /x64** for 64 bits -there is another mode for Itanium but I have never used it-. The Visual Studio IDE is not included because it is a paid product, but good quality compilers for free is a good enough to anyone.